# Calling the base in moq's .Return function

Tags: c#, moq

Say I am mocking up a function, and want to be able to, inside the .Returns statement, call the underlying implementation, make some changes to it, and return it.  Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Create instance of your implementation, then use it when setting up `Returns` ? That said, IMO, you shouldn't depend on Real implementations in unit testing, that's why we're using Mock.